# Django Generic View UpdateView redirect URL with updated slug

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-generic-views

This is my updateview which is called by a URL with slug field, e.g.

```
/mymodel/update/<model_name_slug>/
```

`MyModel` have two fields, `name` and `slug`. The slug field `<model_name_slug>` is automatically generated from `MyModel.name`. If the user update it, a new slug field will be automatically generated. Then, I want to redirect to this new URL with the newly generated slug field.

The slug field auto-generation is working. It is implemented in the `MyModelEditForm`. However, the code below won't work. The reason is:

1) User typed this URL to update the existing model

```
/mymodel/update/example-model
```

2) User changes the Name attribute to `"example model changed"`. Then slug field will be generated as `"example-model-changed"` in `MyModel`.

3) But the URL is not redirected to the `"/mymodel/update/example-model-changed"`, as `get_object()` will return `None. get()` will not be able to compare the newly generated URL `"example-model-changed"` with original `"example-model"`

What am I missing in below code? I tried to access the newly update object using `self.object`, but have following error:

```
 MyModelUpdateView object has no attribute 'object'
```

Here is the code snippet:

```
class MyModelUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = MyModel
    form_class = MyModelUpdateForm
    template_name = 'mymodel/update_mymodel.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        view_name = 'update_mymodel'
        return reverse_lazy(view_name, kwargs={'model_name_slug': self.kwargs.get('model_name_slug','')})

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        '''
        This injects form with keyword arguments.
        '''
        kwargs = super(MyModelUpdateView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        #Update the kwargs with the user_id
        kwargs['user'] = self.request.user
        return kwargs

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # self.object = self.get_object()
        if self.request.path != self.object.get_absolute_url():
            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.object.get_absolute_url())
        else:
            return super(MyModelUpdateView, self).get(request,*args, **kwargs)
            # context = self.get_context_data(object=self.object)
            # return self.render_to_response(context)

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        instance = MyModel.objects.get(slug=self.kwargs.get('model_name_slug',''))
        return instance
```

Even if the get_success_url() is correctly updated, the get_object() seems to have two conflicting requirements:
1) Be able to fetch the correct object using existing "example-model" slug field;
2) Be able to fetch the updated object using newly generated "example-model-changed" before the existing URL is not redirected.

Comment: As an aside, I think that if you set `slug_url_kwarg = 'model_name_slug'` on your view, you won't have to override the `get_object` method.

Comment: Do you mean the slug_url_kwarg will  automatically be the newly generated slug field as shown in the get_success_url?

Comment: No, this is separate from getting the slug in the `get_success_url` - for that, see my answer below. You've overridden `get_object` but you don't have to, just set `slug_url_kwarg = 'model_name_slug'` as a class attribute.

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a shot and let you know. BTW, I have figured out another way to do this and posted it below

Answer (score 6):

You don't have to use `self.get_object` in the `get_success_url` method. The [`form_valid()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.ModelFormMixin.form_valid) sets `self.object` when saving the form, so you can use `self.object.slug` to get the new url.

```
def get_success_url(self):
    view_name = 'update_mymodel'
    # No need for reverse_lazy here, because it's called inside the method
    return reverse(view_name, kwargs={'model_name_slug': self.object.slug})
```

Comment: This works. The one thing to notice here is that the order is --> form_valid() --> inside that there is save() --> After the save there is HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url()), where you may use the updated slug (from self.object.slug).

Answer (score 0):

Haven't used class based view much, but..

```
def get_success_url(self):
        view_name = 'update_mymodel'
        return reverse_lazy(view_name, kwargs={'model_name_slug': self.kwargs.get('model_name_slug','')})
```

If get_success_url is supposed to return the url that you want to redirect user to, shouldn't you use the updated slug not the old one?

`self.get_object().model_name_slug`

I guess this is correctly done atm.

> 1) Be able to fetch the correct object using existing "example-model"
>   slug field;

You want to get the updated url based on updated model for redirect. Where do you create the updated url? get_success_url?. Then I don't see why `reverse_lazy(view_name, kwargs={'model_name_slug': self.get_object().model_name_slug})` doesn't work?

> 2) Be able to fetch the updated object using newly generated
>   "example-model-changed" before the existing URL is not redirected.

Comment: self.get_object() won't be able to return the updated object

Comment: then change the get_object() to use the updated slug not the kwarg's

Comment: I don't think that you need to use `reverse_lazy` unless you're assigning the result to a class variable. User `reverse` instead

Answer (score 0):

Thank Alasdair and eugene for the quick help.

Meanwhile, I have figured out another way to do this! That is, use two arguments in the URL, like  and .

Look up in the stackoverflow URL. Have you noticed something similar? Yes, that is it. 33115530 is the pk, I guess. The rest is slug field automatically generated!

Then, in get_object, the newly updated object will be fetched through the , and get_success_url can use the new slug field updated in the object.