# I can't redirect to the post after editing a comment of that post

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-class-based-views

I can't redirect to the post after editing a comment of that post.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Post(models.Model):
    body = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Comment(models.Model):
    comment = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    post = models.ForeignKey('Post', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**views.py**

```
class CommentEditView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
        model = Comment
        fields = ['comment']
        template_name = 'social/comment_edit.html'
        
        def get_success_url(self):
            pk = self.kwargs['pk']
            return reverse_lazy('post-detail',kwargs={'pk': pk,})
            
        def test_func(self):
            post = self.get_object()
            return self.request.user == post.author
```

**comment_edit.html**

```
{% extends 'landing/base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="row mt-5">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
            <a href="{% url 'post-detail' object.pk %}" class="btn btn-light">Back to Feed</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row justify-content-center mt-5">
        <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-12">
            <h5>Update Your Comment</h5>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row justify-content-center mt-3 mb-5">
        <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-12">
            <form method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form | crispy }}
                <div class="d-grid gap-2">
                    <button class="btn btn-success mt-3">Update</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Here Comment editing is working. But after submitting the edited comment I want to redirect to the post related to the comment.

Comment: Exactly what is happening if you submit the comment? Can you share the relevant model and HTML?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33115530/django-generic-view-updateview-redirect-url-with-updated-slug) might be a possible solution to your question. If it doesn't work reply with more details.

Comment: I have added models.py comment_edit.html & views.py

Comment: can you share your this app url.py file

Comment: `pk = self.kwargs['pk']` gives the pk of the _comment_ object not of the post, also in `{% url 'post-detail' object.pk %}` you are again using the pk of the comment object instead of the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `pk` is the primary key of the *comment*, not the *post*. You redirect with:

```
class CommentEditView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Comment
    fields = ['comment']
    template_name = 'social/comment_edit.html'

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs).filter(
            author=self.request.user
        )
        
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('post-detail',kwargs={'pk': self.object.post_id})
```